# In python, what does pop () select and does it allow indexes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does pop () in python take from the first or last of the set and does it take an index?

Im learning python and i recently came across the pop function while learning about sets. I've tried using pop () on sets, at first it removed the last content in it from the list which was what I expected because that's what they said in geeks for geeks but later it kept taking the first thing from the set, they also said that you can include indexes in the function but that just gave me an error.

```
Nums={73,30,18,36,38}
Nums.pop ()
73
Nums.pop (2)
TypeError: pop () takes no arguments (1 given)
```

I expected the first function to output 38 which is the last number but instead it outputted 73 which was the first .
And when I did it with the index 2 I expected it to output 18 but instead it gave me an error.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.pop)? There is no `.pop(index)`  for `set`! All your questions are answered by the documentation - why ask here?

Comment: To be fair, if he's a beginner programmer, he might not have known about the existence of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`Nums={73,30,18,36,38}` is a **Set**. One attribute of Sets is that they don't have a fixed order. This implies, that `pop()` seems random, while in fact it selects changing 'last items'.
If you use a list, `Nums=[73,30,18,36,38]`, `nums.pop()` will return the last item as expected.
And yes, you can use it with indices.

Comment: But the whole point about using a set in the first place is for the guarantee of item uniqueness and the *O(1)* efficiency at item lookup. A list does none of those.

Answer (score 1):

Sets are unordered in Python, so there is no index associated with items in a set, and the order in which the items are popped is undefined.

If you want an ordered set, an easy workaround is to use a dict instead, as dict keys are by definition unique just like set items, and are guaranteed to follow the insertion order since Python 3.7, and in prior versions you can use `collections.OrderedDict` in place of a dict. Use `itertools.islice` if you need an item at a specific index:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> nums = dict.fromkeys((73,30,18,36,38))
>>> list(nums)
[73, 30, 18, 36, 38]
>>> nums.popitem()
(38, None)
>>> list(nums)
[73, 30, 18, 36]
>>> nums.pop(next(islice(nums, 2, None)))
>>> list(nums)
[73, 30, 36]
>>>
```

Answer (score -2):

Without any parameter, Python `list.pop()` function will return the last item of your **list** (not set), removing it at the same time.

You can specify an index with `list.pop(index)`. This will return the item located at this index, and remove it as well.

Here's an example :

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print(list.pop(1))
# 'b'
print(list)
# ['a', 'c', 'd']
```